# Concurrent Invoice Numbers for a quickbook like invoicing app

Tags: postgresql, backend, sequence

I am building a cloud based ERP, where user can create invoices. The law in India requires gapless invoice numbers. I am using Postgres as database, so what are the best ways this can be implemented to allow multiple users to create invoices and ensure that invoice numbers generated do not have gap between them or are inconsistent (like two invoices having the same invoice number).

Comment: What is to happen when session 1 assigns an  invoice number in proper sequence and then  session 2 also assigns the next invoice number in the proper sequence. However the session 1 has additional work to perform and therefore session 2 commits first. Then a session 1 throws an exception and aborts. Now you have a gap in the invoice number even though they were assigned properly. The only (simple) way is to lock the table containing the sequence number until the transaction commits or aborts. Either way be prepared to accept slow processing.

Comment: A much more complicated process would create a [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/contrib-dblink-connect.html) for generating the invoice numbers.  In the link create a log of assigned invoice numbers (including the client and other required information), and commit. Now back in the initial session any exception processing also accesses through the link and updates the log to show an abort message. This at least keeps all the assigned invoice numbers.

Comment: Is there a way I can lock only the row. In that way the performance is only halted for a company rather than all the companies.